# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x18 in tid 5091

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, crash

I want to build my application on Asus_Z008D but I have this problem:

```
[Mono] Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] Attempting native Android stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]  at ???+0 [0xe20ab667]
[mono-rt]  at mono_class_get_field_from_name+31 [0xe20ab73f]
[mono-rt]  at ???+31 [0xf2f7e9a2]
[mono-rt]  at ???+31 [0xf2f7ebe3]
[mono-rt]  at Java_mono_android_Runtime_init+2127 [0xf2f812b0]
[mono-rt]  at ???+2127 [0xe29dcde2]
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x18 in tid 5091 (ru.roadaccident)
```

Application crashed on LaunchScreen, breakpoints in main activity and LaunchScreen not worked. On other devices app work so well; I using Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Studio; Please, help me;

Comment: I've had this strange error before, for me cleaning the solution solved it.

Comment: I tried to clean solution. It didn't help;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building your APK to support the x86 and x86_64 architectures? The Asus_Z008D uses Intel Atom CPU, not ARM. See:
http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=6a09-4fd1-ffff-ffff924a117c

So if you are only building for ARM architectures, or using any libraries that are only built for ARM, the app won't work on an x86/x86_64 device.